# str_split without word-wrap

Tags: php, string, split, word-wrap

I'm looking for the **fastest solution**, to [split](/questions/tagged/split) a string into parts, without [word-wrap](/questions/tagged/word-wrap).

```
$strText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$arrSplit = str_split($strText, 12);

// result: array("The quick br","own fox jump","s over the l","azy dog");
// better: array("The quick","brown fox","jumps over the","lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You actually can use  [`wordwrap()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), fed into `explode()`, using the newline character `\n` as the delimiter.  `explode()` will split the string on newlines produced by `wordwrap()`.

```
$strText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// Wrap lines limited to 12 characters and break
// them into an array
$lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($strText, 12, "\n"));

var_dump($lines);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "The quick"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "brown fox"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "jumps over"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "the lazy dog"
}
```

Comment: Note: using false (default) as the 4th param prevents words from being broken when wrapping. Exactly what I needed. If you don't care about breaking words, set this to true.