# PHP Split String After X Characters Into Separate Word

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: str_split without word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648019/php-str-split-without-word-wrap)

Let's say I have this string :

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

and I have character limit on my database : 15 characters. by using str_split($string,15), I got this result :

```
Array
(
[0] => Lorem ipsum dol
[1] => or sit amet
)
```

this looks ugly to me... how to cut string to the closest word using PHP but the result is like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Lorem ipsum
[1] => dolor sit amet
)
```

Comment: You can use  str_split function.
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$string = wordwrap($string, 15, ";;", true);
var_dump(explode(";;", $string));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
  1 => string 'dolor sit amet' (length=14)
```

Comment: could you tell what will you do  if the string is like "loremipsum Registered User"

Comment: you can check it your self : http://codepad.viper-7.com/rP2HRL